# Can I use Code First Migrations without pluarized table names?

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

We finally got things squared away so that we can start using code first.

When I run "Enable-Migrations" it creates a file with InitialCreate in it's name.
(like here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx#enabling)

That file has plural database table names instead of singular.

I do have this line in my initiazlizer, which is correct:

```
modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
```

but the file that is being created with the migration has all pluralized names.

This becomes annoying when I add a migration and the first thing it does is drop every pluralized table in the DB and re-add them as singular.

Can I pass a parameter into the "Enable Migrations" command or something to tell it to not pluralize?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This behavior has been fixed, I'm unable to reproduce it with EF 6.1.0. I created the database using an initializer first, than ran `Enable-Migrations` (of course `OnModelCreating()` already includes the line removing the `PluralizingTableNameConvention`). The generated migration (with `InitialCreate` in its name) generates tables named in the singular. So if you're able to update EF your problem will be gone.

If not: did you try to override the table names with their singular form using the [Table](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/EntityFrameworkCodeFirstMigrationsAlphaNuGetPackageOfTheWeek10.aspx) attribute? At least generated migration code does respect it (I haven't checked with an older EF version than 6.1.0 though).

```cs
[Table("MyEntity")]
public class MyEntity
{
    // .. your properties go here.
}
```

Comment: I did try to update to 6.1 before I tried this, but it might be that I hadn't updated all projects.  I'll try again and report

Comment: I haven't had a chance to try it yet.  We've moved on for now, but I know we'll be back at some point and I'll come back and update when we try again.